# Segmentation Fault when looping through 2D Char Array, Wordsearch

Tags: c, arrays, segmentation-fault, char, 2d

My assignment is to create a wordsearch that looks through words in a list (called 'list' in the code) and finds it in a 2D grid (called 'arr'). If a word is found I need to make the words lowercase in the grid and print it out. I need to look in 5 directions, r2l, l2r, t2b, tl2br, and tr2bl. I am able to run the Right to Left comparison and am able to print out the grid with the found words in lowercase. However I get a seg fault every time I attempt to compare in any other direction. Any help?

Puzzle.txt file: https://ucmerced.box.com/s/twkdxega6d34bkou3mpy0xtm901grlx3
states.txt file: https://ucmerced.box.com/s/4zi7etq3wab3y81m64kx6naaiy2bttea

```
#include <string.h>


void printPuzzle(char** arr, int n);
void searchPuzzle(char** arr, int n, char** list, int listSize);

void lowerCaseL2R(char** arr, int y, int x, int lengthOfWord);
void lowerCaseT2B(char** arr, int y, int x, int lengthOfWord);
int searchAll(char** arr, int k, int l, int ii, char** list, int lengthOfWord);
char upperCase(char letter);

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    int bSize = 15;
    if (argc != 2) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Usage: %s <puzzle file name>\n", argv[0]);
        return 2;
    }
    int i, j;
    FILE *fptr;
    char **block = (char**)malloc(bSize * sizeof(char*));
    char **words = (char**)malloc(50 * sizeof(char*));

    // Open file for reading puzzle
    fptr = fopen(argv[1], "r");
    if (fptr == NULL) {
        printf("Cannot Open Puzzle File!\n");
        return 0;
    }

    // Read puzzle block into 2D arrays
    for(i=0; i<bSize; i++){
        *(block+i) = (char*)malloc(bSize * sizeof(char));

        fscanf(fptr, "%c %c %c %c %c %c %c %c %c %c %c %c %c %c %c\n", *(block+i), *(block+i)+1, *(block+i)+2, *(block+i)+3, *(block+i)+4, *(block+i)+5, *(block+i)+6, *(block+i)+7, *(block+i)+8, *(block+i)+9, *(block+i)+10, *(block+i)+11, *(block+i)+12, *(block+i)+13, *(block+i)+14 );
    }
    fclose(fptr);

    // Open file for reading word list
    fptr = fopen("states.txt", "r");
    if (fptr == NULL) {
        printf("Cannot Open Words File!\n");
        return 0;
    }

    // Save words into arrays
    for(i=0; i<50; i++){
        *(words+i) = (char*)malloc(20 * sizeof(char));
        fgets(*(words+i), 20, fptr);        
    }

    // Remove newline characters from each word (except for the last word)
    for(i=0; i<49; i++){
        *(*(words+i) + strlen(*(words+i))-2) = '\0';    
    }

    // Print out word list
    printf("Printing list of words:\n");
    for(i=0; i<50; i++){
        printf("%s\n", *(words + i));       
    }
    printf("\n");

    // Print out original puzzle grid
    printf("Printing puzzle before search:\n");
    printPuzzle(block, bSize);
    printf("\n");

    // Call searchPuzzle to find all words in the puzzle
    searchPuzzle(block, bSize, words, 50);
    printf("\n");

    // Print out final puzzle grid with found words in lower case
    printf("Printing puzzle after search:\n");
    printPuzzle(block, bSize);
    printf("\n");

    return 0;
}
void printPuzzle(char** arr, int n){
    int i, j;
    for(i = 0; i < n; i++){
        for(j = 0; j < n; j++){
            printf("%c", *(*(arr + i) + j));
            if(j == (n - 1)){
                printf("\n");
            }
        }
    }
}
void searchPuzzle(char** arr, int n, char** list, int listSize){
    //arr is puzzle block (wordsearch), n is 15, list is a 2D array of words we are searching for (states), listSize is 50;

    int i, j, k, l, m, lengthOfWord = 0, found = 0;
    for(i = 0; i < listSize; i++){
        for(j = 0; (*(*(list + i) + j) != '\0'); j++){
            //number of iterations is equivalent to length of word;
        }
        lengthOfWord = j;
        for(k = 0; k < 15; k++){
            for(l = 0; l < 15; l++){
                if(*(*(arr + k) + l) == *(*(list + i))) {
                    found = searchAll(arr, k, l, i, list, lengthOfWord);
                    if(found == 1){
                        lowerCaseL2R(arr, k, l, lengthOfWord);  
                    }
                    if(found == 2){
                        lowerCaseT2B(arr, k, l, lengthOfWord);  
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
int searchAll(char** arr, int k, int l, int ii, char** list, int lengthOfWord){
    int dir1, i1, i2, count1 = 0, count2 = 0;
        for(dir1 = 0; dir1 < lengthOfWord; dir1++){
            if((*(arr + k) + (l + dir1))){
                if(*(*(arr + k) + (l + dir1)) == (upperCase(*(*(list + ii) + dir1)))){
                    count1++;
                }
                if(count1 == lengthOfWord){
                    printf("Found: ");
                    for(i1 = 0; i1 < lengthOfWord; i1++){
                        printf("%c", *(*(list + ii) + i1));
                    }
                    printf("\n");
                    return 1;
                }
            }
        }
        /*(for(dir2 = 0; dir2 < lengthOfWord; dir2++){
            if((*(arr + k + dir2) + l)){ // if(*(*(arr + k + dir2) + l)) != '\0' did NOT work
                if(*(*(arr + k + dir2) + l) == (upperCase(*(*(list + ii) + dir2)))){
                    count2++;
                }
                if(count2 == lengthOfWord){
                    printf("Found: ");
                    for(i2 = 0; i2 < lengthOfWord; i2++){
                        printf("%c", *(*(list + ii) + i2));
                    }
                    printf("\n");
                    return 2;
                }
            }
        }*/

return 0;
}

char upperCase(char letter){
    if(letter >= 'a' && letter <= 'z'){
        letter = letter + ('A' - 'a');
    }
return letter;
}


void lowerCaseL2R(char** arr, int y, int x, int lengthOfWord){  
    for(int i = 0; i < lengthOfWord; i++){
        *(*(arr + y) + (x + i)) = *(*(arr + y) + (x + i)) + ('a' - 'A');
    }
}
```

Comment: [Edit] your question and show the code that calls the functions. The problem (or at least a part of it) may be there. Also don't show pictures of text. Show text as text.

Comment: @Jabberwocky im fairly certain that my main function works flawlessly, nonetheless i edited the question with it attached

Comment: Please provide a minimal puzzle file that reproduces the problem. Also provide a minimal `states.txt` file.

Comment: It would be much easier to help if you used a fixed puzzle (showing the failure) instead of reading the puzzle from a file that we don't have! So drop the file reading and fill out the puzzle directly.

Comment: OT: The `fscanf` with 15 `%c` makes it impossible to change `bSize`. You should read one char at the time - and do it `bSize` times

Comment: This: `for(i=0; i<49; i++){` seems strange to me. Why 49 when you use 50 in other loops?  And do you know that "states.txt" always have (at least) 50 words?

Comment: OT and opnion based... This `*(*(arr + i) + j)` is IMO hard to read. Consider the form `arr[i][j]` instead. This goes for all places in the file - use `[..]`

Comment: OT: In C, don't cast `malloc`

Comment: @jabberwocky I provided links to the grid as well as a list of words I need to search for

Comment: @Jabberwocky the main function should not cause any issues; I want to fix the functions so that it doesn't cause a seg fault, also malloc is mandatory